# Error: " stray '##' in program in

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, c++

I am trying to use #define in Arduino IDE as I used to do in Atmel Studio like:

```
#define PROGRAM(N) void PROG_##N(void)
```

However I am getting a stray error because of the hashes, is there a way to implement this better?

Aim: `PROGRAM(5){}` becomes void `PROG_5(void){}` and so on.

Comment: It compiler in my Arduino IDE. Code:  (using \n as newlines): 

#define PROGRAM(N) void PROG_##N(void) \n
PROGRAM(5){}\n

void setup(){}\n
void loop(){}

Comment: What version of the IDE are you using? You're not a Linux user that used `apt-get` to install it are you?

Comment: It is working now, the mistake was actually in a different file but Arduino IDE 1.8.8 kept saying it is here which was confusing. Thanks.